# Probability proof with triangle difference inequality

Tags: probability

I'm reviewing a proof and I'm having trouble understanding why the first line is less than the second line. 
$$P(|\hat{Z}| < c)$$
$$\leq P(|Z| - |\hat{Z} - Z | < c)$$
$c$ is a positive real.
$\hat{Z}$ is a random variable,
$Z$ is the population parameter that $\hat{Z}$ estimates.  $Z \neq 0$.

My steps so far: 
$$P(|\hat{Z}| < c)$$ 
$$=P(|\hat{Z} - Z - (-Z)| < c)$$
$$=P(|(-Z)-(\hat{Z} - Z)| < c)$$
$$\leq ? P(|(-Z)|-|(\hat{Z} - Z)| < c)$$
The triangle difference inequality indicates that 
$$|a - b| \geq |a| - |b|$$

because of this, shouldn't the inequality with the question mark be the other way around.    Does it matter what the distribution of $\hat{Z}$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using triangle inequality,notice that

$$|Z|=|Z-\hat{Z}+\hat{Z}| \leq |\hat{Z}-Z|+|\hat{Z}|$$

Thus,

$$|Z|-|\hat{Z}-Z|\leq  |\hat{Z}|$$

if we have $|\hat{Z}| \leq c$ , therefore $|Z|-|\hat{Z}-Z| \leq c$

So the event $ \{|\hat{Z}| \leq c\} \subset \{|Z|-|\hat{Z}-Z| \leq c\}$, finally,

$$P(|\hat{Z}| \leq c) \leq P(|Z|-|\hat{Z}-Z| \leq c)$$

The distribution of $Z$ does not matter